# Open custom LaunchScreen.storyboard via URL Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, url, launch-screen

It looks like there is an API to open my app via an URL scheme and show a custom LaunchScreen based on the URL scheme used. The API was explained in radar://22569482 and you can see a screenshot of the exaplanation here: https://twitter.com/AriX/status/689639170206134272‌

I've tried to create a sample project that uses both .xib and .storyboard files as LaunchScreen but it doesn't look like to work. Is there any more key required to be configured in order to work?

This is my Info.plist file so far: https://gist.github.com/BalestraPatrick/e857bc34bcef8f37b86a

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, this API support both .xib and .storyboard file.

If you launch your app from Home Screen, it works (with the default Launch Screen you configured).

But... if you launch from a URL Scheme, it will just show you the app's previous snapshot. Well, previously, if you are not use this API, it will show you the default Launch Screen.

So maybe the UIURLToLaunchStoryboardAssociations key is wrong.

Have to wait Apple to explains the details.